# Java Multi-Client Chat Application - Sending messages issue

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sockets

My problem is, I can still send messages between Clients(Client-to-Client) but after sending two or three times, messages are no more displayed to the recipient.

So basically whenever the Client wish to send a message to another Client, the message is first sent to the server. But as you have noticed from my coding, I am sending the server data in form of an object. 
For example:

```
send(new ChatMessage(type, sender, content, recipient));
```

When you send a message the type is "message". When the server receives the object, it checks the receive data and its type. 
For example:

```
ChatMessage cm = (ChatMessage) in[client[id].readObject();
if(cm.type.equals("message"){
  send(findUserThread(toWhom), new ChatMessage("message", sender, content, recipient);

}
```

If the type is "message", then it sends that specific client the message.

I am using System.out.println() at the Client side to see the incoming data from server. So when I try to send some messages, it is working fine but then after sending some messages nothing is display on my chat screen.

According to my logic the errors can be:

1 Selected index in JList

2 Client[] array or username[] array

3 ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream

ServerGUI class(Server Side)

```
package test2;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public JList online;
private JTextField ipaddress, textMessage;
private JButton send, start, disconnect;
private JTextArea chatArea;
private JLabel port;
int client[] = new int[100];
private ObjectOutputStream out[] = new ObjectOutputStream[client.length + 1];
private ObjectInputStream in[] = new ObjectInputStream[client.length + 1];
String username[] = new String[client.length + 1];
static String b;
public String nm, usm;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connect;
boolean success = true;
int id = 0;
ArrayList<String> UserList = new ArrayList<String>();


public ServerGUI() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 500));


    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    p.add(port = new JLabel("Port No"));
    p.add(ipaddress = new JTextField("1500"));
    p.add(start = new JButton("START"));
    p.add(disconnect = new JButton("DISCONNECT"));
    disconnect.setEnabled(false);
    start.setBorderPainted(false);
    start.setBackground(Color.blue);
    start.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    disconnect.setBorderPainted(false);
    disconnect.setBackground(Color.blue);
    disconnect.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    ipaddress.setCaretPosition(0);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    p1.add(chatArea = new JTextArea());

    chatArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 350));
    chatArea.setLineWrap(true);
    chatArea.setEditable(false);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    p2.add(textMessage = new JTextField(20));

    p2.add(send = new JButton("SEND"));
    send.setBackground(Color.blue);
    send.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    send.setBorderPainted(false);

    start.addActionListener(this);
    send.addActionListener(this);


    c.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


}
//current time
SimpleDateFormat log = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String d = log.format(new Date());

//Start server
public void Start() {

    int portNo = 0;
    try {

        String no = ipaddress.getText();
        portNo = Integer.parseInt(no);
        chatArea.append("Connection to port " + portNo + "...\n");
        server = new ServerSocket(portNo);
        success = true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        chatArea.append("Error cannot bind to port \n");
        success = false;
    }

    if (success == true) {
        addClient ob1 = new addClient("RunServer");
        start.setEnabled(false);
        disconnect.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

public class addClient implements Runnable {

    Thread t;

    addClient(String tot) {
        t = new Thread(this, tot);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    WaitClient();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    break;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
                    if (client[i] == 0) {
                        client[i] = i + 1;
                        id = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //set stream to send and receive data
                out[client[id]] = new ObjectOutputStream(connect.getOutputStream());
                out[client[id]].flush();
                in[client[id]] = new ObjectInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
                chatArea.append(d + " Client:[" + client[id] + "] : Connected successful \n");
                chatArea.setCaretPosition(chatArea.getText().length());
                //inform user that connection is successfull                    
                ChatMessage cm = (ChatMessage) in[client[id]].readObject(); // read client username
                if(cm.type.equals("login")){
                    chatArea.append("User " +cm.sender + " connected successfully" + "\n" );
                    username[client[id]] = cm.sender;
                    System.out.println(username[0]+ username[1]+ username[2]);
                    send(client[id], new ChatMessage("login", username[client[id]], "user", "SERVER"));
                    sendUserList(cm.sender);
                    Announce("newuser", "SERVER", cm.sender);




                }




                Chat c = new Chat(client[id], "StartChat" + client[id]); // make new thread for every new client 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}

public class Chat implements Runnable {

    int id1;
    Chat ob1;
    Thread t;

    Chat(int id1, String info1) {
        this.id1 = id1; // create a thread for client
        t = new Thread(this, info1);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
     boolean running = true;
       while(running){
            try {
                ChatMessage cm = (ChatMessage) in[client[id]].readObject(); // read client username
                if(cm.type.equals("message")){

                         send(findUserThread(cm.recipient), new ChatMessage(cm.type, cm.sender, cm.content, cm.recipient));


                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
       }

    }
}




//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void WaitClient() throws IOException {

    chatArea.append(d + " : Waiting for connection... \n");
    connect = server.accept();

    chatArea.append(d + " : Now connected to " + connect.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n");
}

//send message to specific user
public void sendUser(int number, String info) {

    try {
        out[number].writeObject(info);
        out[number].flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void sendServer(String por) {
    for (int i = 0; i < client.length; i++) // for loop trying to send message from server to all clients 
    {
        if (client[i] != 0) // this line stop server to send messages to offline clients
        {
            try {
                out[i + 1].writeObject(por);
                out[i + 1].flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Announce(String type, String sender, String content){

    ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage(type, sender, content, "All");
    for(int i = 0; i < id; i++){
        send(client[i], cm);
    }
}



public void send(int number, ChatMessage cm) {

    try {
        out[number].writeObject(cm);
        out[number].flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}





void sendAll(int num, String por) {
    for (int i = 0; i < client.length; i++) // for loop trying to send message from server to all clients 
    {
        if (client[i] != 0) // this line stop server to send messages to offline clients (if "clientNiz[X] = 0" don't try to send him message, because that slot is empty)
        {
            if (num != i + 1) // don't repeat messages (when for ex. client_1 send message to all clients, this line stop server to send same message back to client_1)
            {
                try {
                    out[i + 1].writeObject(por);
                    out[i + 1].flush();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void sendUserList(String toWhom){
    for(int i = 0; i <= id; i++){
        send(findUserThread(toWhom), new ChatMessage("newuser", "SERVER", username[client[i]], toWhom));
    }
}

public int findUserThread(String usr){
    for(int i = 0; i <= id; i++){
        if(username[client[i]].equals(usr)){
            return client[i];
        }

    }
    return -1;
}

  private int findClient(int num){  
    for (int i = 0; i <= id; i++){
        if (client[i] == (num+1)){
                return i;
            }
}
return -1;
}





public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == send) {
        //current time

        String s1 = textMessage.getText();
        send(client[id], new ChatMessage("message", "admin", s1, "client"));
        chatArea.append("Administrator: " + s1 + "\n");


    } else if (e.getSource() == start) {
        Start();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == disconnect) {

        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < client.length; i++) {
            try {
                in[i].close();
                out[i].close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        chatArea.append("Server is disconnected\n");
        start.setEnabled(true);
        disconnect.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```

MainGUI class(Client Side)

```
package test2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class MainGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainGUI() {
    initComponents();





}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    start = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    textMessage = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    chatArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    usernm = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    send = new javax.swing.JButton();
    upload = new javax.swing.JButton();
    filename = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    online = new javax.swing.JList();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("ICARE ");
    setFocusable(false);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(840, 650));
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    jButton1.setText("Video Call");
    getContentPane().add(jButton1);
    jButton1.setBounds(270, 10, 100, 30);

    jButton3.setText("Send");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton3);
    jButton3.setBounds(690, 100, 100, 30);

    start.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    start.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    start.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    start.setText("Start");
    start.setBorder(null);
    start.setBorderPainted(false);
    start.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            startActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(start);
    start.setBounds(630, 50, 90, 40);
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(0, 0, 820, 0);
    getContentPane().add(textMessage);
    textMessage.setBounds(270, 450, 420, 70);

    chatArea.setColumns(20);
    chatArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    chatArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(chatArea);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane2);
    jScrollPane2.setBounds(270, 140, 520, 300);
    getContentPane().add(usernm);
    usernm.setBounds(450, 60, 170, 30);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Enter your nickname:");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(270, 60, 150, 30);

    send.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    send.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    send.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    send.setText("Send");
    send.setBorder(null);
    send.setBorderPainted(false);
    send.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sendActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(send);
    send.setBounds(700, 470, 90, 40);

    upload.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    upload.setText("+");
    upload.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            uploadActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(upload);
    upload.setBounds(633, 100, 50, 30);
    getContentPane().add(filename);
    filename.setBounds(270, 100, 350, 30);

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(online);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(30, 20, 220, 500);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    Start();


}                                     

private void sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String z = textMessage.getText();
    String target = online.getSelectedValue().toString();
    chatArea.append("[ " + usernm.getText() + " ] : " + z + "\n");

    send(new ChatMessage("message", usernm.getText(), z, target));
    textMessage.setText("");         


}                                    

private void uploadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //Create a file chooser
//In response to a button click:
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showDialog(this, "Select File");
    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    if(file != null){
        if(!file.getName().isEmpty()){
            String str;

            if(filename.getText().length() > 30){
                String t = file.getPath();
                str = t.substring(0, 20) + " [...] " + t.substring(t.length() - 20, t.length());
            }
            else{
                str = file.getPath();
            }
            filename.setText(str);
        }
    }
}                                      

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
      long size = file.length();
        if(size < 120 * 1024 * 1024){
            sendUser("download");


        }
        else{
            chatArea.append("File is size too large\n");
        }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainGUI().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
public javax.swing.JTextArea chatArea;
private javax.swing.JTextField filename;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
public javax.swing.JList online;
private javax.swing.JButton send;
private javax.swing.JButton start;
private javax.swing.JTextField textMessage;
private javax.swing.JButton upload;
private javax.swing.JTextField usernm;
// End of variables declaration


private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;
static String b; //variable for message
private Socket join;
boolean success = true;
private String serverIP = "127.0.0.1"; //set IP Address
ArrayList<String> userlist = new ArrayList<String>(); //ArrayList to store online users
//current time
SimpleDateFormat log = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String d = log.format(new Date());
public File file;
public DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();



//Start client program
public void Start() {

    try {

        start.setEnabled(false);
        chatArea.append(d + " : Attempting connection... \n");

        join = new Socket(serverIP, 10500);
        chatArea.append(d + " : Connected to - " + join.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n");

        success = true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        chatArea.append("Error cannot bind to port \n");            
        success = false;
    }

    if (success == true) {

        ClientThread ct = new ClientThread();


    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    ClientThread ct;
    Thread t;

    ClientThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "RunClient");
        t.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(join.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
                in = new ObjectInputStream(join.getInputStream());

                send(new ChatMessage("login", usernm.getText(), "password", "SERVER"));                
            } catch (Exception e) {   }



            CThread c1 = new CThread();


        } catch (Exception ex) {   }
    }
}

class CThread implements Runnable {

    CThread ob1;
    Thread t;

    CThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Message");
        t.start();
    }


    public void run() {
        boolean running = true;
        try {
            while(running){
                try {

                    ChatMessage cm = (ChatMessage) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Incoming :" + cm.toString());
                    if(cm.type.equals("login")){
                     chatArea.append(cm.sender + " is online" + "\n");
                    }else if(cm.type.equals("message")){                           
                        if(cm.recipient.equals(usernm.getText())){
                                 chatArea.append("[ "+cm.sender +" ] : " + cm.content + "\n");

                        }
                   }else if(cm.type.equals("newuser")){

                        online.setModel(model);
                        model.addElement(cm.content);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}





void sendUser(String por) {
    try {
        out.writeObject(por);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

void send(ChatMessage cm){
    try {
        out.writeObject(cm);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}


}
```

ChatMessage class

```
package test2;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ChatMessage implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String type, sender, content, recipient;

public ChatMessage(String type, String sender, String content, String recipient){
    this.type = type; this.sender = sender; this.content = content; this.recipient = recipient;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "{type='"+type+"', sender='"+sender+"', content='"+content+"', recipient='"+recipient+"'}";
}
}
```

ServerTest to run ServerGUI

public class ServerTest
   {
    public static void main(String args[]){

```
    ServerGUI m = new ServerGUI();

    m.setTitle("Server");

    m.setVisible(true);

    m.pack();

    //to make to the center of the screen

    m.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


}
}
```

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Classes in Java should start with uppercase. For example: `ServerGUI` but not `addClient` as seen in your code.
- Classes represent objects. Or "classes" of objects. For example `Car` or `ServerGUI` but not `addClient`. What is an `new addClient()`? Is that an object really?
- Variable names should have significant names if possible. For example `Car limousine = new Car(4,Color.Black)` and not `addClient ob1 = new addClient("RunServer")`. What does `ob1` mean?
- Comments are fresh air for readers. Please, use comments. For example: `//we are going to represent the server as a special user with admin privileges`
- Method names ir Java should not start with uppercase. This is a bad example: `private void WaitClient() throws IOException`
- Indent and blank lines. Don't know if it is your fault partly or completely but the code is bad indented, has blank lines inside blocks (not just one or two, nor acting as separator), and misses spaces (`if(cm.type.equals("login")){`)
- *StackOverflow is not a good place for your problem. Here people ask specific questions. Yours is not a specific question, it is more a "my program doesn't work" problem.*

In conclusion: your code is **hard to read and understand**. It seems you are new to Java so please, start with simple and easy examples, use a Java IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans and take your time! You won't learn Java in a week, be patient.

Sorry if I've been too honest but that's what I think (and probably one of the reasons nobody else here is helping you).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. This will definitely help me to get better in programming. I am really grateful for your contribution. Thanks :)

Comment: That's the attitude! Sorry for not solving your problem but you have to solve a lot of small problems first hehe. Take your time and come again when you have a specific question we can answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> But after sending two or three messages, my program stop sending messages

First of all you should try to debug your application. Using logs or `System.out.println` you can easily find out where is it "stopping". Is the message being sent to the server? Is the server sending the message to the client? You can answer these questions with just a few `println`.

Once you know where (in your code, which method) it is failing you can post a more specific question if you still need help.

Also when you have a problem, please explain what problem it is really, in detail. Does the application crash? Does it stop sending messages to everybody? "my program stops sending messages" is a little bit vague.

**EDIT:** Well, now that I see the code, please, do not do this:

```
void send(ChatMessage cm){
    try {
        out.writeObject(cm);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

If an exception is thrown, you won't notice.
You should add:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

inside **every** `catch()` block so you can see errors in console when they occur.

Nobody likes red messages in console, but hiding them is not going to help. Always print errors, or log them, or both :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll make the necessary corrections :)

Comment: I added e.prinStackTrace everywhere I could, but still I am having the same problem when I am sending messages and no error message is displayed in the console. I am really confused but I am confident I can find the error.

Comment: update the code and add `ChatMessage` class so we can run it.

Comment: Added the ChatMessage class! In the ServerGUI class you need to add the main method. When you test it try to send a few messages to another client. Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to run it? Actually the problem I believe can be with threads synchronization. If possible could you explain me how do I synchronize two threads.

Comment: I have tried all what I could but still having the same problem. I added synchronization to all my methods used in the threads. I really need help for this one.

Comment: I have noticed one more thing when I tested once more my chat application. For example User 1 and User 2 are chatting. When User 1 sends messages to User 2 everything is fine but once User 2 wish to send messages to User 1 nothing is sent. And I also noticed if another User want to connect to the server, the UserList for that user is not updated.

Comment: I still can't run the server (there is no main). `MainGUI`: line 298, line 305, line 345 (weird try/catch inside a try/catch), line 358, line 366... it is full of empty catch blocks. You will never see an Exception with that code. Also you are asking a lot of questions here, thread synchronization, exceptions... please, do not post all your problems in a single question as this won't help anyone except you. Divide your problem in small problems and again, add `println` in every method so you can see where the error is.

Comment: I did add prinStackTrace() where I have a try and catch. But believe me there were no error mentioned in the console. I added the ServerGUI main method. Thanks